# Task/Method scheduling from within a timer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, timer, scheduled-tasks

From within a Windows service I would like to cast a method *once* an hour. A polling timer exists which I would like to use rather than adding a "Windows Task".

In the timer callback, I am checking whether to call the method or not by the following code, where _config.PollingInterval is the interval of the timer.

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, 0, 0)) < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_config.PollingInterval)) {
    SendReport();
}
```

For some reason, the condition is met twice within the same minute (e.g. 08:00). I guess there is a logical error somewhere, since it's assured that there is only *one* timer.

Any hints for a working or even completely different/more elegant approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
class Reporter
{
    int _HourLastRun;

    public Reporter()
    {
        _HourLastRun = -1;
    }

    public void SendIfNeeded()
    {
        var currentHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;

        if(currentHour != _HourLastRun)
        {
            _HourLastRun = currentHour;
            SendReport();
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply instantiate this class where you create your timer and put the `SendIfNeeded()` into the callback of the timer.

Comment: This does its job pretty well, shame I didn't think of that... Thanks! (Still waiting for the acception-timeout..)